# Empty Win32 Popup Menu

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a dynamic popup menu within my application, the generation code I use is something like that :

```
    HMENU   menu;
    POINT   pt;

    menu = CreatePopupMenu();

    SetForegroundWindow( receivingWindow );
    GetCursorPos( &pt );
    int i = 19;
    AppendMenu( menu, MF_STRING, i++, _TEXT("meh meh") );
    AppendMenu( menu, MF_STRING, i++, _TEXT("testo") );
    AppendMenu( menu, MF_STRING, i++, _TEXT("foobar foobar") );
    TrackPopupMenuEx( menu
                    , 0
                    , pt.x, pt.y
                    , receivingWindow
                    , NULL );

    DestroyMenu( menu );
```

`_TEXT` is used to ensure text is in Unicode and `receivingWindow` is a Layered window created before and working well.

When calling `TrackPopupMenuEx` the menu is displayed with the good size and at the good position, but absolutely no text appear in the popup menu. Did someone got an idea why, and how to fix this problem?

EDIT: more information regarding my environment :

- Windows 7 x64
- x86 build in Visual Studio 2008

EDIT2: I've tested the same on Windows XP x86, and it works like a charm, and after further test, the menu is well displayed in Windows 7 x64 with the classic look.

Comment: You are not setting any values in the fuFlags parameter of TrackPopupMenuEx().  Try specifying some alignment and mouse options.  That might help it better decide how to behave.

Comment: Even with fuFlags, no text displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem. Instead of using my main window (`receivingWindow`), I'm using a message only window to receive the event. For a reason that I don't understand, the text is displayed normally this way.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure ::DefWindowProc() is called for messages that aren't handled otherwise. I had a similar issue with TrackPopupMenu() where the menu would popup with the correct size and allow items to be selected, but there was no text on the items because the code was ignoring some messages without calling ::DefWindowProc().

Comment: Did not help her :-(

Answer (score 1):

In my case i created the menu with "CreateMenu" but i must use "CreatePopupMenu" to use it with TrackPopupMenuEx.

If the menu is created in the resource editor check if the flag is set.

Comment: This solved my issue thanks (no text was being displayed when using CreateMenu)

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is not set to compile for unicode (i.e #ifndef UNICODE) then winuser.h will map AppendMenu to AppendMenuA which is a non-unicode version and would interpret your strings as multi-byte. Perhaps this explains your issue? 
You could explicitly call AppendMenuW() (the unicode version) to check if this is your issue.

Comment: Sadly, UNICODE is already defined and AppendMenuW is well called.

Comment: _TEXT() is also affected by the presenceof, or lack of, UNICODE define.  If UNICODE is not defined, AppendMenu() maps to AppendMenuA(), but the text inside _TEXT() also maps to Ansi instead of Unicode.  So there is no conflict here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the function TrackPopUpMenuEx doesn't return immediately; thus after it initiates (and presumably chooses it's size and position) but before it first displays you are destroying the menu.

As I understand it you need to destroy the menu after your window has received the command message from a menu selection. Alternately use the TPM_RETURNCMD flag in TrackPopUpMenuEx as this forces trackpopupex to only return after a menu item has been selected (as opposed to immediately).

Comment: When I put a breakpoint on DestroyMenu, it break only after I've clicked on any blank item in the menu. Again I can see the menu, the text is just invisible :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
call    GetSubMenu,mnu,0
call    TrackPopupMenu,eax,TPM_CENTERALIGN or TPM_BOTTOMALIGN,cposx,cposy,0,MainhWnd,0
```